# how to split string?

Tags: c#

```
<span style="cursor: pointer;">$$</span>
```

how can i get `<span style="cursor: pointer;">` and `</span>` from this string. Everything around $$.

No need to be regex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you could just use:

```
string[] bits = input.Split(new string[]{"$$"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Note that unlike the overloads taking `char` separators, you *have* to provide the `StringSplitOptions`, and you *have* to manually create the array. (Of course if you're going to do this repeatedly you would probably want to reuse the array.) You can also optionally specify the maximum number of tokens to split the input into. See the [string.Split overload list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7h14879.aspx) for more information.

Short but complete program:

```
using System;

public static class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "<span style=\"cursor: pointer;\">$$</span>";
        string[] bits = input.Split(new string[]{"$$"},
                                    StringSplitOptions.None);

        foreach (string bit in bits)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(bit);
        }
    }    
}
```

Of course if you know there are only going to be two parts, another option is to use `IndexOf`:

```
int separatorIndex = input.IndexOf("$$");
if (separatorIndex == -1)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("input", "Oh noes, couldn't find $$");
}
string firstBit = input.Substring(0, separatorIndex);
string secondBit = input.Substring(separatorIndex + 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use IndexOf to find the "$$" and then use a Substring method to get either side.

Example

```
        string s = "<span style=\"cursor: pointer;\">$$</span>";
        string findValue = "$$";

        int index = s.IndexOf(findValue);

        string left = s.Substring(0, index);
        string right = s.Substring(index + findValue.Length);
```

Comment: I was just adding exactly that to my answer :)

Comment: :) I'd expect no less from the legend of Skeet

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SubString() method:

```
string _str = "<span style=\"cursor: pointer;\">$$</span>";
int index = _str.IndexOf("$$");
string _a = _str.Substring(0, index);
string _b = _str.Substring(index + 2, (_str.Length - index - 2));
```

Mitja